# Extracting the real part of an UnsafeMutablePointer as a Float and storing that on an array

Tags: swift, pointers, unsafemutablepointer

I have this function

```
func arrayForPointer<T>(_ pointer: UnsafePointer<T>, count: Int) -> [T] {
let buffer = UnsafeBufferPointer<T>(start: pointer, count: count)
return Array(buffer)
}
```

and this call

```
let arrayComplex = self.arrayForPointer(&output, count: 4)
```

I want to enumerate thru `arrayComplex` and extract the real part to a regular array, like

```
var arrayReal: [Float] = []

for item in arrayComplex {
  let myFloat = item.realp  \\ get the real part of item
  arrayReal.append(myFloat)
}
```

line

```
let myFloat = item.realp  \\ get the real part of item
```

is not correct.

`item` is a `UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>`

How do I do that, for heavens sake?

Thanks.

=======================

This is `output`

```
var A = [Float](repeating:0, count:samples/2);
var B = [Float](repeating:0, count:samples/2)
var output = DSPSplitComplex(realp: &A, imagp: &B)
```

Comment: What is your `output`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

Fix your func call:

```
let arrayComplex = arrayForPointer(output.realp, count: 4)
```

And then in your loop fix this line:

```
let myFloat = item  \\ get the real part of item
```